# Show that $\angle {ABC }$ is bisected by line OC

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, geometric-construction, tangent-line

[image]

Here is the construction

[image]

Show that $\angle {ABC }$ is bisected by line OC, Got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In step iii, you are asked to construct a circle that literally touches all three line segments that form the triangle (without extending the sides of the triangle). Spoiler alert for step iv: this is called the *incircle* of a triangle. See [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incircle.html) for more details, but in general it should look like:
[image]